How do I fix mobile broadband/WWAN with Quectel EM061K-GL on ThinkPad T14 Gen 5 21MC (AMD) running Ubuntu 24.04.1?
I just got a T14G5-21MC and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 24.04.1 on it. It was unable to see the Qualcomm FastConnect 7800 Wi-Fi adapter at first, but a kernel update addressed that (had to search and install 6.11 from official apt repo). However, the mobile broadband still isn't working.
I attempted to enable it with mmcli -m 0 --enable but I get couldn't enable interface: 'Invalid transition'. I read somewhere this was about the card being FCC-locked, so I downloaded the script from the Lenovo support to unlock it, but running it did nothing helpful. The status report still reads
  Status   |                    lock: sim-pin2
           |          unlock retries: sim-pin2 (10)
           |                   state: enabling
           |             power state: low

despite it not being PIN-locked.
The following commands did not help:

mmcli -m 0 --reset
mmcli -m 0 --set-power-state=on
sudo rfkill unblock all (hard and soft blocks were already off)
sudo systemctl restart ModemManager

Starting to get in over my head here. How do I make this work?

Found the magic unicorn forum thread here with the answer!
Find the device name:
sudo ls /dev/cdc*

Should be /dev/cdc-wdm0. Query the device's RadioState to see if it reports as being FCC-locked:
sudo mbimcli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -v --quectel-query-radio-state

If so, run this to unlock modem:
sudo mbimcli -p -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -v --quectel-set-radio-state=on

Finally, enable the modem:
sudo mmcli --modem 0 --enable

Once I added my APN (h2g2 for Google Fi), it worked beautifully.
